# Schedule a c# program in windows task scheduler

Tags: c#-4.0, scheduled-tasks

I have some code I want to run every 30 minutes. In the windows task scheduler -> Create Task -> Action -> new  - there is a place to insert it a script/program.
My question what kind of project I need to create to add there my program, and what kind of file I need to add - dll?

What I wish to run every 30 minutes is a 30~ lines of code that get something from then net, process it and insert it to a db.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont really care what is it, I guess it can be an exe..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Task Scheduler runs ordinary EXEs.

You don't need to do anything special.

Comment: But bear in mind that the EXE will run but not be visible, so if you trigger a winform application for example you won't see the form.

Comment: @Dan: That depends which user you set the task as.

Answer (score 4):

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

    class Program
    {
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    // Get the service on the local machine

    using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
    {

     // Create a new task definition and assign properties
      TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
      td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

         // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
         td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger { DaysInterval = 2 });

         // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
         td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

         // Register the task in the root folder
         ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

         // Remove the task we just created
         ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
        }
     }
   }
```